# Should a table connecting two tables have its own ID?

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

```
First
------
id
name

Second
------
id
name
```

And another table connecting the first two:

```
Third
------
first_id
second_id
```

The third table is there *only* to resolve the M:N issue. Should it have its own ID?

Comment: It is merely a question of style i.e. how much of a fan are you of surrogate keys? put one on every table; put one on every table except relationship/join/junction/linking/other_name_here tables; use only where I can't be bothered to find a an existing/roll my own key; use only when fully justified; will do anything to avoid a surrogate key; etc.

Comment: Well my style is: don't use something if you don't need to.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If the table only contains the two foreign keys, there is no reason to have an additional key. You won't be using it in any query.

When you join the tables using the connection table, you are making a join against one foreign key at a time, not against both foreign keys at once, so there is no use for another key in the connection table. Example:

```
select t1.name, t2.name
from First t1
inner join Third t3 on t3.first_id = t1.id -- one foreign key
inner join Second t2 on t2.id = t3.second_id -- the other foreign key
```

Just make a primary key combining the two foreign keys.

```
 PRIMARY KEY (first_id, second_id)
```

Comment: I edited your answer a bit, so the answer is complete now. Thanks!

Comment: What if I want to link a forth table to both first and second table? Can I use id of the third table(which represents first and second table, ie., relationship table's id) in my forth table in this case?

Comment: @Rao: Yes, you can, but it might be more convenient to have an additional key in the third table in that case.

Comment: @Guffa In my case here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33277220/1161412 an additional key is not feasible I think, could you take a look at it please?

Comment: What if I want to sort this relational table by the order it was inserted (or DESC)? Is there a way without an INT PK for each row?

Answer (score 7):

No, you normally don't need an id field on the table connecting the two. You can make the primary key for the connecting table (first_id, second_id).

Comment: What if my forth table needs to link to first and second table? Does it make sense to have an ID column in the relationship table then? Can I use this relationship ID to make the link between my forth table and the first and second table?

Answer (score 5):

If it's just a simple mapping table, then I would say no.  What purpose would that extra ID serve?  Just make the primary key a composite: (first_id, second_id).

Having said that, I have seen cases where it's arguable to have a separate ID because it's easier to work with some ORM tools.  But generally I would say you should avoid the extra ID column if you can.

Answer (score 5):

I started using Composite PKs out of the two columns and it worked for me for a while.

As business grew and business rules changed, some of these table started getting additional attributes or participating in relationships and then I either needed to add a single column PK or just carry a double key down (which grows old real fast).

I decided then to standardize my own design. Now, as a part of my design, I use an additional single column PK for all join tables.

Comment: I think you are right; In my experience a link table can often become an entity in its own right.  Strictly, though, the extra Id is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on role of the table "'third" (connection or join table). Lets assume for example, that this table express a relation between two others tables. Since it is all, there is no need for additional Id.

But what if that relation, between table "One" and "Two" became temporary? I mean, that relation is for some period of time. For example ownership, marriage, etc. Then you can't add another record/entity to the connection table ("Third") because such a relation already exist.

So it is safer to establish for each table it's own Id. Exept we are sure, that in the future, temporary (since that multitimes) relation will not happen.

=========================================
sorry for my english