# Postgres: How Can I Make a JOIN/Junction Table Which References *One Of* Two Other Tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgres database, and it has a `Foo` table and
a `Foo_Group` table.  It also has a `Bar` table, and all of these tables have a simple `id` primary key column.

I'd like to create a many-to-many relationship between the three, such that a `Bar` can have 0+ `Foo`s and 0+ `Foo_Group`s.  I can create a `Foo_and_Foo_Groups_Bar` JOIN table easily enough, with foreign keys to `Foo`, `Foo_Group`, and `Bar`.  However, I'm having trouble creating the primary key on my JOIN table.

The problem is, in `Foo_and_Foo_Groups_Bar` either `foo_id` or `foo_group_id` will always be `NULL` ... but primary key columns can't have `NULL`s.  The only solution I've been able to find is to put an `id` column on `Foo_and_Foo_Groups_Bar` ... but I thought JOIN tables *weren't* supposed to have their own ID, and were supposed to use their JOIN ID columns as the primary key.

So what is "correct" here?  Do I add a (seemingly unnecessary, except to make the constraint happy) column to my JOIN table, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a fan of synthetic primary keys.  You can add a `serial`/`generated always as identity` column for a primary key.  And then add a unique constraint for the triplet of ids.

I'm not 100% sure from your example that you are talking about a single relationship.  It sounds like you have two relationships, one between `bar` and `foo` and another between `bar` and `foo_groups`.  If that is the case, then you can have two bridge tables and don't have to worry about `NULL` values.

Comment: But my concern is, isn't it "wrong" to add a separate ID column to a JOIN table?  Shouldn't its primary key somehow come from the combination of `foo_id`, `foo_group_id`, `bar_id`?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556298/should-a-table-connecting-two-tables-have-its-own-id

Comment: So is the Stack Overflow answer I linked wrong then?  Just trying to understand the "rules" of good DB architecture here.

Comment: @machineghost . . . There are arguments for and against synthetic keys in this case.  That doesn't mean that one way or the other is "wrong".

Comment: Ok, so "don't put an ID column (synthetic key) on your JOIN table" isn't one of those rules like "JOIN tables should always be used for many-to-many relationships, and should always have 2+ foreign keys" ... it's more like "you should name your database tables singularly/plurally" (ie. different database devs disagree)?

Comment: Yes.  For instance, it is not uncommon for "bridge" tables to be used for foreign key relationships themselves -- and in that case, an integer primary key would be a best practice.